# Responsive design with two fixed sized divs at sides and a div for the rest in the center

Tags: css, responsive

I have a header with three elements like this:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
#container div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
#container #left,
#container #right {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">L</div>
  <div id="center">CENTER</div>
  <div id="right">R</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like is to make it responsive so it covers the whole width of the window, but the side divs (left and right) need to preserve the same size  so the only one that needs to change the size is the center one. How can I achieve this in CSS?

Comment: you will have to make use of media queries: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Uhmm I don't think so

Comment: then, it's not responsive... it keeps the same aspect without taking care of the width of the window

Answer (score 2):

For example

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#container div {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1;
}
#container #left,
#container #right {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">L</div>
  <div id="center">CENTER</div>
  <div id="right">R</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the divs:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
#container div {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  background: green;
}
#container #left,
#container #right {
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

#container #left {
  float: left;
}

#container #right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">L</div>
  <div id="right">R</div>
  <div id="center">CENTER</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **absolute position** of left and right div.

```
    #container #left, #container #right {
    width: 50px;
    background-color:red;
    float:right;   
    position:absolute;
}
#container #center {
    width: 100%;
    margin:0px auto;        
    background-color:blue;
   float:left;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="left">L</div>
     <div id="center">CENTER</div>
     <div id="right">R</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   *
   {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   }
   #container {
   width: 100%;
   }
   #container div {
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   }

   #container #left,
   #container #right {
   width: 50px;
   border:1px solid red;
   }
   #center
   {

   border:1px solid blue;
   width: calc(100% - 115px);
   margin:auto;
   }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ht3o5n81/

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#container #center{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#container #left,
#container #right {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">L</div>
  <div id="center">CENTER</div>
  <div id="right">R</div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps.